# Por que a classe SplStack não serializa com a função json_encode?

Tags: php

No PHP existe um problema quanto a serialização do objeto. Geralmente isso é resolvido quanto a classe que se tenta serializar implementa a interface `JsonSerializable`.

```
class Obj implements JsonSerializable
{
   protected $items = array();

   public funciton __construct($items)
   {
      $this->items = $items;
   }

   public function jsonSerialize()
   {
       return $this->items;
   }
}


json_encode(new Obj(array('1', '2', '3')); // "[1, 2, 3]"
```

Percebi que algumas classes, mesmo que se tratam de estrutura de dados, não implementa essa interface. E como resultado tive problemas - o que não tive em `ArrayObject`, mesmo que esta também não implemente `JsonSerializable`.

Veja:

$a = new SplStack;

```
$a[] = 1;

$a[] = 2;

$a[] = 3;

var_dump(json_encode($a)); //Imprime: "[]"
```

Como se pode ver `SplStack` não retornou nada quanto serializada por `json_encode`.

Por que isso acontece com essa classe em específico? Seria um bug?

Answer (score 1):

No caso do exemplo da pergunta o retorno é vazio porque os itens adicionados estão dentro de uma propriedade(`dllist`)  privada logo ela não está acessível para `json_encode()`.

Caso uma função externa tivesse acesso aos membros privados da classe, isso violaria o encapsulamento.

```
<?php
$a = new SplStack;
$a[] = 1;
$a[] = 2;
$a[] = 3;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
```

Saída:

```
plStack Object
(
    [flags:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => 6
    [dllist:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Aí surge outra dúvida http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92495/como-arrayobject-%C3%A9-serializada-por-json-encode-j%C3%A1-que-a-mesma-n%C3%A3o-implementa-js